# How hard is it to manage a TypePad blog? Should I host it myself or get hosted service?

Tags: blog, typepad

I have had difficulties in the past using Wordpress and have been thinking about moving to Typepad.

How difficult is it to manage a Typepad installation? Should I just install it myself on a shared host or should I pay for the hosted service? What sorts of limitations does the hosted service impose?

Comment: Typepad's self-install analog is MovableType. You can install MT on a shared server. http://www.movabletype.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing Typepad is extremely easy.  I've used them extensively in the past for our corporate blog, and been fairly happy with their service. The only complaint I've had is that they're somewhat barebones, feature-wise, in exchange for very high uptime and a very simple user interface.

As far as I know, Typepad doesn't even offer a host-it-yourself service; that's part of their value: they host it for you.  The advantage over a service that does do self-hosting (such as Blogger) is that you don't need to worry about maintaining your own server, handling bandwidth, and so on.  The downside, obviously, is that you'll pay Typepad rates for hosting media, which are probably a bit higher than what you'd pay for using a shared host.

Comment: Blogger doesn't offer self-hosting.    Wordpress does, though.